# How to restore from hotcopy backup in Trac

Tags: ubuntu, trac

I have a hotcopy backup file from the trac

```
sudo trac-admin /trac/projectname hotcopy /home/user/desktop/projctname.tracbkp
```

How do i restore this into another project says "projectName2"

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `projctname.tracbkp` directory to, say, `/trac/projectName2`, tweak the `conf/trac.ini` file (looking for references to the old name and replacing them with the new one), and configure your webserver for the new location.